# How to obtain hidden state ids from a wav2vec2 model?

Tags: pytorch, huggingface

with the following code I extract the hidden state from a wav2vec2 model, but I wonder is it feasible to obtain corresponding token ids. Many thx to any suggestions/comments.

```
import librosa
import torch
from transformers import Wav2Vec2FeatureExtractor, Wav2Vec2Model

input_audio, sample_rate = librosa.load("/content/bla.wav",  sr=16000)

model_name = "facebook/wav2vec2-large-xlsr-53"
feature_extractor = Wav2Vec2FeatureExtractor.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = Wav2Vec2Model.from_pretrained(model_name)

i= feature_extractor(input_audio, return_tensors="pt", sampling_rate=sample_rate)
with torch.no_grad():
  o= model(i.input_values)
print(o.keys())
print(o.last_hidden_state.shape)
print(o.extract_features.shape)
```